# use cron to implement 'From 12:24:20 to 16:20:56 Every 5 minites'

Tags: cron, cronexpression

how to implement a cron job like this:

From 12:24:20 to 16:20:56
run every 5 minutes

or Is there a solution on Python, I use package `APScheduler`

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solve the problem myself, I extend the APScheduler library and define a customized Trigger to fullfill my requirement. Useful links:

http://pythonhosted.org/APScheduler/extending.html

http://devlvl99.blogspot.com/2013/03/injecting-timezone-awareness-python.html